# Shader output mismatch

Tags: opengl-es, shader, glsles

I have the below shader and I am testing these on different mobile devices.

http://glsl.heroku.com/e#14148.0

On some device like the Moto G. I get an unpleasant behavior. Instead of the center being a circle, I see it
as a square.But on devices like Nexus 7 and Nexus 4 it is a circle.

Is there any way to make it always a circle. is it due to precision effects?

Answer (score 0):

Just If some one wanted to know.

This was because the precision was set to lowp. Making it highp  solved the issue.